# xslt: default namespace and null namespace when creating a new element

Tags: xslt

Looks to me xslt does not differentiate default namespace and null namespace.

Should `ElementB.namespace-uri()` be `"http://ns1"` or `""` below?

```
<ElementA xmlns="http://ns1">
  <ElementB/>
</ElementA>
```

How about `ElementB.namespace-uri()` below:

```
<ElementA xmlns="http://ns1">
  <ElementB xmlns=""/>
</ElementA>
```

Should `ElementB.namespace-uri()` be different for the above two cases?  When I tried with xslt 1.0, however, it returns `""` for both cases.

I wonder how to differentiate the two cases (default namespace and null namespace)?  How to add an element with null namespace with xsl to generate `<ElementB xmlns=""/>`?

**New update:**  I think it is my debugger issue.  Now I see the default namespace is returned as expected in case 1.

Howver, for case2 (with null namespace), how can I create an element with null namespace?   Using xslt, I'd like to change the following xml

```
<ElementA xmlns="http://ns1">
  <ElementB xmlns=""/>
</ElementA>
```

To:

```
<ElementA xmlns="http://ns1-new">
  <ElementB xmlns=""/>
</ElementA>
```

I'm using a stylesheet adapted from michael.hor257k ([Replace namespace node string value with xslt---what is wrong with my xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545035/replace-namespace-node-string-value-with-xslt-what-is-wrong-with-my-xsl)):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="nsmapdoc" select="document('maps.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="old-ns" select="namespace-uri()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="map-entry" select="$nsmapdoc//namespace[@source=$old-ns]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="new-ns">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$map-entry">
            <xsl:value-of select="$map-entry/@target"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$old-ns"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>   
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$new-ns}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the above xsl, I see the following

```
<ElementB xmlns=""/>
```

is wrongly transformed to

```
<ElementB/>
```

So I guess the question should be:how to add a null namespace using xsl?

**Update 2:**

It is the right way to add null namespace.  It is the processor problem.  The processor I was using is "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl" (the default one in JDK?).  The problem is gone after I change to "org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl" and add the needed xalan jars.

Thank you for the input!

Comment: How exactly are you testing this? In your first example, ElementB inherits the namespace from its parent; in the second example, it is in no namespace. This is **before** the transformation. You are not showing us the transformation you are using, so we  are in no position to tell what is happening.

Comment: XSLT should return `"http://ns1"` in the first case and `""` in the second. Please supply complete runnable code to show exactly what you are doing and exactly what results it is producing.

Comment: I updated the question above.  It is my trying to create an element with null namespace not working as expected.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Using a map.xml document that contains only one entry `<namespace source="http://ns1" target="http://ns1-new"/>` the result received for ElementB is  `<ElementB xmlns=""/>`. Tested with Saxon and Xalan. The result with libxslt is syntactically different, but semantically the same. Which processor are you using, and what is the **full** result for the given example?

Comment: I am using "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl"   that is included in JDK.  I used jaxp interface (TransformerFactory and Transformer) to transform.  For the given example, I got the following result where <ElementB /> is not correct:                                 <ElementA xmlns="http://ns1-new">
  <ElementB />
</ElementA>

Comment: Found the issue.  It works if the namespace is "  " instead of "".   So it should be <xsl:element name="xxx" namespace="  ">.

Comment: Where does `<xsl:element name="xxx" namespace=" ">` appear in your stylesheet?